With enableEdgeToEdge, dark mode doesn't work properly
According to this documentation, if we want to enable edge-to-edge on API 34 and lower devices, we must call this method in the activity:
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       enableEdgeToEdge()
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       ...
     }

Problem: When I use this method, the dark mode does not work properly, some views are dark and some are light!
Considering that the target SDK of my app is 35 and I have used codes like below in all activities, is it necessary to use enableEdgeToEdge() again? And if I don't use it, there may be problems such as overlap in devices with an API lower than 34?
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(fab) { v, windowInsets ->
  val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
  v.updateLayoutParams<MarginLayoutParams> {
      leftMargin = insets.left,
      bottomMargin = insets.bottom,
      rightMargin = insets.right,
  }

  WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}


I also had enableEdgeToEdge() make problems with system bar contrast on API < 29.
The following workaround (shown here in Java) is simple, reliable, and avoids needing to test older API versions for compatibility problems with edge-to-edge mode and inserts vs. light/dark modes, color themes, screen rotations, etc.
    private static final boolean EDGE_TO_EDGE = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 35;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (EDGE_TO_EDGE) {
            EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        if (EDGE_TO_EDGE) {
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(mainContainer, this::mainWindowInsetsListener);
        }
        ...
    }


Finally I used setDecorFitsSystemWindows instead of enableEdgeToEdge, I don't know if this solution is reliable or not, but I tested it on a few devices and it worked.
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    }

